# I am not able to get the data from database into a textbox

Tags: c#

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["electionConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updatedata();
    }
public void updatedata(){
    int ward_no =Convert.ToInt32((Session["wardno"]));
    string query = "select ward_no,part_no,part_leader1_name,part_leader1_mob,part_leader2_name,part_leader2_mob,t_streets,t_families,t_electoral,t_male,t_female,t_others from f_field_details where ward_no=@ward_no";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ward_no", ward_no);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    if (reader.Read())
    {

        txtward.Text = reader["ward_no"].ToString();
        txtpart.Text = reader["part_no"].ToString();
        txtleadername.Text = reader["part_leader1_name"].ToString();
        txtphne1.Text = reader["part_leader1_mob"].ToString();
        txtname1.Text = reader["part_leader2_name"].ToString();
        txtphneno.Text = reader["part_leader2_mob"].ToString();
        txtstreets.Text = reader["t_streets"].ToString();
        txtfamilies.Text =reader["t_families"].ToString();
        txttotvotes.Text = reader["t_electoral"].ToString();
        txtMen.Text = reader["t_male"].ToString();
        txtWomen.Text = reader["t_female"].ToString();
        txtothers.Text = reader["t_others"].ToString();
    }

}
}
```

this is my coding, i am getting the data from the database after the user is entering the data in the previous page after they click the submit button I am redirecting them into the next page that is this page, the issue is the data is getting inserted into the database but will retrieving the data from the database is not working. to get the data am using a where condition in the query and the object for the condition is coming from the previous page using session. the issue is the data is not displayed in the textboxes

Comment: did this "int ward_no" get the value from session?

Answer (score 2):

There are few corrections in your code:

1. The session["string"] will return on object, that may or maynot be convertiable as an integer so better to use `int.TryParse()` instead for `Convert.To..()`.
2. Reader may get null reference if reader has no rows, so i suggest you to check for `reader.HasRows` before accessing value from it. or use [`While(reader.Read())`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Retrieving data using a DataReader involves creating an instance of
>   the Command object and then creating a DataReader by calling
>   Command.ExecuteReader to retrieve rows from a data source. The
>   following example illustrates using a DataReader where reader
>   represents a valid DataReader and command represents a valid Command
>   object.

3. Use [`Parameters.Add()` instead for `Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

So your code looks like this(and this may solve your problem too):

```
int ward_no=0;
int.TryParse(Session["wardno"].ToString(), out   ward_no);
 string query = "select ward_no,part_no,part_leader1_name,part_leader1_mob,part_leader2_name,part_leader2_mob,t_streets,t_families,t_electoral,t_male,t_female,t_others from f_field_details where ward_no=@ward_no";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ward_no", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ward_no; //this will be the type of field
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
while (reader.Read())
{ 
    // assign values here
}
```

Comment: this seems to be a feasible solution ! Try this